# Azure Data Factory to call on-prem Alteryx API

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, alteryx

I need to start a job in Alteryx (on-prem) from an ADFv2 pipeline and can't find a way to do so.  The built in Web activity doesn't seem to support OAUTH 1.0 signature process that Alteryx requires.  When trying to configure, I always get the error "Error calling the endpoint".  I've tried using the Web Activity + HTTP Linked Service and can't figure out the correct way to do this.  I need to do a POST (start job) and a GET (get job status) to an on-prem Alteryx API and I'm not even sure which activity is the best activity to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U're right: web activity doesn't support more complex scenarios than just a simple request, and linked service doesn't support oAuth 1.0 auth.

From my point of view you're gonna have to extract the signature process that oAuth 1.0 requires. You could do one of the two:

- Use a custom activity where u're going to code the signature process and also call your Alteryx job.
- Use something like an Azure Function to do the signature process and call your job. And then use the web activity to call your function (it's like calling a normal api with some custom headers for auth).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  A combo of your options that you described is the solution I've come up with.  I'm generating the Signature in custom code and outputting it to the next task Web activity.  Unfortunately, I still can't get the Web Activity to work with my on-prem Alteryx API even when using the Private I.R. setting.  It would be helpful if ADF gave more than generic errors because I can't tell if it's even hitting the API or something on the local network is stopping it.  Which I think might be the case.  Thank you for the response!

Comment: I should add, I've already written a complete .Net project that will call Alteryx.  It works 100% when I run the executable from within the on-prem network.  But when I install it to Blob storage and use Batch Services to execute it, I get an error saying it can't resolve the URL.  I think it's because the Batch Service is in Azure and not connected to on-prem.  I've tried using my Private I.R. for the Batch Service Linked Service but it doesn't seem to matter.  Ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but unfortunately I don't have any more ideas about your problem. From what you describe it seems like a networking issue. Does the Alteryx API is supposed to remain private and only reachable from inside the intranet of your local network?

Comment: It was definitely a network issue for the batch services custom activity.  I had to extend the on-prem domain to Azure via VPN etc.  But, I'm still trying to figure out why I can't get the Web Activity to work since it uses a self-hosted IR.  I should be able to generate the Key in custom activity that OAuth 1.0 requires and then pass it on to the Web Activity as a parameter.  But I can't get the Web Activity to recognize my API url correctly.

Comment: Glad to hear that part of the problem has been resolved! So what's left is that the Web Activity hits your Alteryx Api right? What's the error that the web activity throws?

Comment: I opened a ticket with MSFT around the Web Activity.  They confirmed that the Web Activity cannot use IRs and therefore cannot connect to an on-premise source.  So I am stuck doing this within Custom Activity/Batch Services.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a ticket with Microsoft, and this was the response:

> Currently the web activity can only run in ADF web role, not IR. This means the web activity does direct calls from the Azure servers to the end points, and is not capable of doing so through a self-hosted IR.

Comment: This is what I found out too.  I had to use batch services and install my code on the VM within batch services.